# How to pass std::optional struct that contains std::unique_ptr to a function?

Tags: c++, function, c++17, unique-ptr, stdoptional

I am learning how to use `std::optional`, and I am having trouble passing a `std::optional<Type>` parameter to a function, since Type contains within it a `std::unique_ptr`, which prevents the call.

What is the correct way to pass such a variable (`std::optional<Type>`) to a function?

Here is a code snippet that easily reproduces the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct myStruct
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> a;
};

int func(const myStruct& val, std::optional<myStruct> opt)
{
    if (opt.has_value())
    {
        return *(opt.value().a);
    }
    else 
    {
        return *(val.a);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World";
    myStruct val;
    val.a = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    std::optional<myStruct> opt = std::nullopt;
    myStruct temp;
    temp.a = std::make_unique<int>(10);
    opt = std::move(temp);
    std::cout << "result is " << func(val, opt) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error I see for the code above:

```
main.cpp:35:47: error: use of deleted function ‘std::optional::optional(const std::optional&)’
     std::cout << "result is " << func(val, opt) << std::endl;
                                               ^
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/optional:453:11: note: ‘std::optional::optional(const std::optional&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class optional
           ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/optional:453:11: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::_Enable_copy_move::_Enable_copy_move(const std::_Enable_copy_move&) [with _Tag = std::optional]’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/optional:43:0,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/enable_special_members.h:157:15: note: declared here
     constexpr _Enable_copy_move(_Enable_copy_move const&) noexcept  = delete;
```

Comment: You're making a copy when it's passed to `func`. Take it by const reference or such.

Comment: Wow, a simplified, clear [mcve] of your issue and as the first question, +1 ; it's too rare around here.

Comment: On a side note, at least in Java it is discouraged to have `Optional` for parameters as there is already a concept for optional parameters; different overloads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `myStruct` is indirectly only movable (non-copyable), because of the member [`std::unique_ptr<int> a;`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr), which is also by default non-copyable (only move is allowed).

Therefore the optional variable `opt` (which contains the struct `myStruct`) is also indirectly only movable. However, in your function `func` you are trying to pass `opt` by value, which in effect tries to copy the underlying struct and hence the compiler error.

You need to pass `opt` by  *const ref*, as you are not modifying `opt` anyway.

```
int func(const myStruct& val, const std::optional<myStruct>& opt)
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
   // ..code
}
```

[See live](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/17EsfWrcr)

Comment: Thanks @Jejo! this worked. I considered optional as an equivalent of unique_ptr and so this never crossed my mind!